# Can I store my fermentation containers filled with sanitizer liquid

Tags: storage, sanitizer

Is there a maximum time I can keep the sanitizer liquid inside the fermentation containers? Would it be OK if I fill them with it and store them for a while, like a couple of weeks?

If not, would it be OK for a few days. Sometimes I fill them with the sterilizer to start some brewing, but then something else comes up and I don't find time to return to it until the next weekend.

I saw that the sanitizer powder tends to fall out from the water after I while and then just lies on the bottom of the container. Sometimes I stir it, to mix it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a powdered sanitizer, like One Step, it doesn't respond well to storage.  It's a percarbonate based sanitizer that depends on O2 to work.  If you store a mixed solution long, the O2 bubbles out making it unreliable.  If you use Iodophor, you can store it for a week or 2 until it loses its color.  It you use StarSan and mix it with distilled water, you can keep it almost indefinitely.  I've had some in a spray bottle for 2 years and it was still good.  So the answer basically comes down to depending on what sanitizer you use, how you mix it, and how you store it.

Comment: At the moment I use "VWP sterilizer" which is a white powder.

Comment: See my answer to your other question.

Comment: Thanks, I already saw it. I will try to change the sanitizer.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to clean my carboys right after I rack the beer into the next container.  I find it's easier to scrub out the sticky bits if you clean right away.  After the cleaning, I don't sanitize, and then I store the carboy upside down with a piece of paper towel on the bottom to catch any leftover liquid.  Since I keep it closed up in storage, I can keep it free of dust for the next batch.  When I brew again, then I do a quick rinse and sanitize it before use.